# htaccess: internal redirect, relative or absolute

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For a internal redirect which of the below is correct (relative or absolute URL)?

```
redirect 301 /mypage-ab /
```

or

```
redirect 301 /mypage-ab http://www.example.com/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A `Redirect` will always be external.

I guess using a path *should* be possible, but all the examples in the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) use full URLs.

If you want to rewrite URLs internally, look at [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) or [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will follow the links